# Azure Service Bus - avoid processing messages from same device in parallel

Tags: azure, concurrency, azureservicebus

A number of devices are sending messages which end up in a single Azure Service Bus queue (or topic). We want to process multiple messages in parallel, but we want to **avoid concurrent processing of two messages of the same device** at any given time.

The following pictures illustrates the goal. There are 3 processing threads (in reality there might be several dozens, distributed between several servers). Each box denotes processing time of a single message, and the color shows which device it belongs to.

[image: Concurrent processing of the messages]

You can see that at no point in time there are two or more overlapping messages originated from the same device.

As there are multiple processing servers involved, I can imagine that the only way to prevent concurrent processing is to partition messages with device ID as partitioning key, and then only have a single consumer for each partition:

[image]

So, all messages from "yellow device" go to partition 1, and so on.

I still want to run multiple processing threads in the single process. Right now, we do something simple like

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
var options = new OnMessageOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = x };
client.OnMessage(m =>
    {
        // Process...
        m.Complete();
    });
```

How do I incorporate the concurrency limitation into such code?

I can imagine some client-side solutions based on actors or other concurrency mechanisms. But is there a way to solve that on Broker level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks as a good candidate to take advantage of the ASB`s Sessions feature. You will be able to use`OnMessage` API, but processing of a given session will only be done by a single consumer, not multiple. Also, you'll be able to run concurrently, handling the load as it comes.

A good starting point would be to look at [`QueueClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesessionasync.aspx) API. If you want a solid documentation with explanation how it works, [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/Sessions/) is the best doco you'll find.

Comment: I've looked at sessions but got an (incorrect?) impression that they are aimed to group processing of related messages together in a single transaction. Thanks for the link to Azure Samples, it looks like `IMessageSessionAsyncHandler` is what I need. I'm not yet sure if I have to close sessions at some point in case of unbounded session lifetime.

Comment: That is correct. I've subbed your message "streams" are not infinite. And as such, would represent a session. In case that's not the scenario, sessions are not the right option for you.

Comment: In the specific case I'm looking at streams have limited lifespan, but it can be up to several days, and it's a bit difficult to say when exactly the last message is received.

Comment: Processing messages in order _and_ having an consumer affinity is generally not a good idea when dealing with competing consumers. And ASB is a such. Don't have other ideas :(

Comment: We've implemented sessions in our solution, and are now testing them with a couple of queues. So far so good, so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks Sean!