# Equivalent Session with Masstransit for concurrency with Saga

Tags: concurrency, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a list of messages on the bus for the same session Saga, I want update the same Saga for each message that Saga receive, the messages are receive in same time for the same session. But to manage concurrency and to avoid concurrency exception, I want use this session feature that provide Azure Service Bus,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions
How to do this with MassTransit, it's an equivalent ?

Same question but not with Masstransit:
[Azure Service Bus - avoid processing messages from same device in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284979/azure-service-bus-avoid-processing-messages-from-same-device-in-parallel)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unit test sets up a message and receive endpoint so that the queue requires a Session to enforce concurrency.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Tests/Session_Specs.cs

There is also a sample that shows how to use Azure Service Bus as the saga repository, using the session state to serialize and store the saga instance:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Tests/SagaRepository_Specs.cs